# Looking for a more compact syntax (simple code) - C++

Tags: c++

I'm relearning C++ and I found myself often writing pieces of code like this:

```
vector<string> Text;
string Line;

while (getline(cin, Line))
{
    Text.push_back(Line);
}
```

I was wondering if there is a more compact way to write the loop using only basic features (no user-written functions, for example) - more or less, putting everything in the condition?

Comment: loop with single instruction, how this can be more compact? Empty loop?

Comment: This is as basic as it gets. It reads from `cin` input stream until `getline()` fails.

Comment: *Why* do you want it to be more compact?  What advantage does that give you?  It certainly won't make it any more readable!

Comment: "Compact syntax" and "simple code" are not always (rarely?!) the same thing. So which one do you want?

Comment: If you want compact, use `std::string::reserve` and `std::cin::read`.  This will read the file into one large string (provided you reserved enough space), thus the data is more *compact*, leaving less holes or gaps in memory.  Also, two statements, thus being more *compact* in the source code.  Search the internet for "memory mapped files", append your operating system name to the keywords.

Comment: For more compact, search the internet for "c++ text compression".

Answer (score 10):

You can use a for loop.  We can declare `Line` in the variable declaration part and use the condition and increment parts to read and place the line.  That gives you

```
for(string Line; getline(cin, Line); Text.push_back(Line));
```

Comment: More compact? And readability? We have a read function, result for comparisons of a loop and a function inside. So writing it as for/do while/while or whatever will not make the thing better!

Comment: @Klaus The user doesn't want better, they want more compact

Comment: Ha. I really like this. It also doesn't require a hack to deal with `push_back` being `void`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah.  I was thinking if using your solution then I remembered I could just do it in the increment step.

Comment: Is meaning "compact" reducing the number of lines or number of characters? ;) Not clear requirements if your code is the solution ;)

Comment: @Klaus: There does not exist a solution to something that doesn't have a problem, such as the code that the OP presents ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, at the expense of some obfuscation,

```
while (getline(cin, Line) && (Text.push_back(Line), 1));
```

would do it: note the use of the *expression separator operator* which, informally speaking, "converts" the `void` return type of `push_back` to an `int` so enabling its use with the short-circuiting `&&`.

But as a rule of thumb, work *with* the language, not *against* it. My answer is doing the latter. The way you present the code in your question is adequate.

Comment: Good example for using obscurity ;)

Answer (score 2):

> more or less, putting everything in the condition?

You can do this

```
while (getline(cin, Line) && (Text.push_back(Line),true)) {}
```

It works because `&&` is short-circuited and because the comma-operator evaluates the first operand, discards the result and returns the result of the second operand.

So it is possible, but why would you want to do that? Making code as dense as possible is rarely good for readability (actually your original code is more readable **and** uses less characters).

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of "but that is exactly OP's code!", I would personally favor this version if this is the entire body of a scope (e.g. function that parses the text):

```
vector<string> Text;
string Line;

while (getline(cin, Line))
  Text.push_back(Line);
```

Alternatively, if part of a larger scope, I would probably group all four lines together and add empty lines before and after for visual coherence (and maybe add a short comment before it):

```
// [lots of other code]

// Gather input from cin.
vector<string> Text;
string Line;
while (getline(cin, Line))
  Text.push_back(Line);

// [lots of other code]
```

I am aware that this introduces no clever tricks, but this is the *most compact and readable* form of the given code, at least to me.

If you wanted compactness above all else, you could choose garbage variables, omit all unnecessary whitespace and even alias the types beforehand (since we are "often writing" this kind of code this is a one-off) to, say,  `V<S> t;S l;while(getline(cin,l))t.push_back(l);`  but nobody wants to read that.

So clearly there is more than compactness at play. As for me, I'm looking to keep noise to a minimum while retaining intuitive readability, and I would suggest this is an agreeable goal.

I would never use the "throw everything into the loop condition" suggestions because that very much breaks how I expect code to be structured: **The main purpose of your loop goes into the loop body.** You may disagree/have different expectations, but in my eyes everything else is just an attempt to show off your minifying skills, it does not produce good code.

The above accomplishes just that: The braces are noise for this simple operation, and the important part stands out as the loop body. "But is `getline` not also important?" - It is, and I would honestly prefer a version where it is in the loop body, such as a hypothetical

```
vector<string> Text;
while (cin.hasLine())
  Text.push_back(readLine(cin));
```

This would be an ideal loop to me: The condition *only* checks for termination and the loop body is *only* the operation we want to repeat.

Even better would be a standard algorithm, but I unaware of any that would help here (ranges or boost might provide, I don't know).

---

On a more abstract level, if OP frequently writes this exact code, it should obviously be a separate function. But even if not, the "lots of other code" example would benefit from that abstraction too.

Answer (score -3):

Loop with a single instruction. you can write it in one line but I don't recommend it

```
while (getline(cin, Line)) Text.push_back(Line);
```

Comment: "Loop is a single instruction" what does this mean?

Comment: The same as in the code given by OP. Leaving the braces is typically a bad idea!

Comment: Sorry with and not is :) I wrote it too fast sorry.